# Training a neural network with complex valued weights (initialized complex valued weights real valued inputs)

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, neural-network, mathematical-optimization

As the question states. I am aiming to train a neural network where the weights are complex numbers. Using the default scikit learn netwokrs and building on this (editing the source code) the main problem I have encountered is that the optimizing functions used in scikit learn taken from scipy only support numerical optimization of functions whose input are real numbers.

Scikit learn is rather poor for neural networks it seems specially if you are wishing to fork and edit the structure is rather unflexible.

As I have noticed and read in a paper here I need to change things such as the error function to ensure that at the top level the error remains in the domain of real numbers or the problem becomes ill defined.

My question here is are there any standard libraries that may do this already ? or any easy tweaks that I could do the lasagne or tensorflow to save my life ?

P.S. : 
Sorry for not posting any working code. It is a difficult question to format to the stackoverflow standards and I do admit it may be out of topic in which case I apologize if such.

Comment: What are you using for NN in SciPy, BTW?

Comment: scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b

Comment: all of the constrained optmizers cast to real for the optmizing variable :/

Comment: OK, thanks <padding>.

Comment: What makes a complex number different from a 2-d Feature. What do you expect to be different from providing real and imaginary part as separate neurons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to divide your feature into the real and imaginary components.  I've done similar work with vector input from a leap motion and it significantly simplifies things if you divide vectors into their component axis.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow has elementary complex number support.

If you have to build the neural network nodes by yourself, you can take a glance at this [blog](https://giggleliu.github.io/complex_bp/).

For **holomorphic** functions, complex BP are fairly straight forward.

For **non-holomorphic** functions, they need careful treat.